# Retrieve value posted from MVC3 aspx view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

views are different from web forms? I can't seem to access my server controls on the view. 
With a webform you can retrive the value of a textbox as `<name>.Text` as long as it's a server control. How am I supposed to do this in MVC3? I'm using aspx views.

I know the value is in the Request.forms collection but isn't there a less ugly way to retrive the value of  a textbox.

Comment: You should Google "ASP.NET MVC Model Binding" and you will get a lot of examples on how you can do this elegantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean accessing the values in the *action*, not in the view.

There are several ways, one is by accepting them as parameters of your action method ([*model binding*](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspNetMVCModelBinding.aspx); [another sample](http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2010/02/25/asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx)), the other is manually read `Request.Form` as you suggested.

**But this is a very short answer.** You *must* [learn MVC basics](http://www.asp.net/mvc) before you try to dive into the water and code. In MVC, the chance that you'd do the wrong thing (against MVC's architecture) is very high if you don't learn the theoretical stuff before.

Comment: Yeah I mean't the action. The view is just the presentation layer and has nothing to do with the data. Silly me.